# Не переключается radio

Tags: css3, html5

Не переключается radio. Все по правилам, но что-то не так. Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Менял дизайн, по итогу только одна нажимается и все - переключения между ними нет.

```css
.radio {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}
.radio + label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
}
.radio + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9FD468;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}
.radio:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.radio:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.7);
}

// for old browsers

.radio {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}
.radio + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio:not(checked) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}
.radio:not(checked) + label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
}
.radio:not(checked) + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
}
.radio:not(checked) + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9FD468;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}
.radio:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.radio:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.7);
}


// end ===================================
```

```html
<form id="formCalculator" name="myForm" action="#"><br><br><br>
  
  <div class="rb">

        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio" name="rassrochka"/>
        <label for="radio">А я переключаю радиокнопку</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio" name="rassrochka"/>
        <label for="radio">А я переключаю радиокнопку</label>
        
</form>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: id - англ. identifier - идентификатор. Его смысл в том, чтобы быть уникальным на странице, чтобы по нему находили элемент) Нужно или разместить инпуты внутри label и убрать for и id... или использовать разные id.

Answer (score 1):

Большую часть ваших стилей не трогал, только убрал `:not()` и отдельную "старую" версию.

Если немного упростить, будет работать так:

```css
/* P.s. в CSS комментарии оставляют так */

.rb label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio { /* Настоящее и невидимое радио */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}

.radio + .custom-radio { /* Серый кружочек */
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio + .custom-radio::after { /* Зеленый индикатор чекнутости */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9FD468;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.radio:checked + .custom-radio::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.radio:focus + .custom-radio {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7);
}

.radio ~ img {display: none; margin: 10px 230px;}
.radio:checked ~ img {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="rb">
  <label>
    <input class="radio" checked type="radio" name="rassrochka" />
    <div class="custom-radio"></div>
    А я переключаю радиокнопку
  </label>

  <label>
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="rassrochka" />
    <div class="custom-radio"></div>
    А у меня противогаз!
    <img src="https://gyazo.com/2d2807366a0504075d817996b920c50a.png">
  </label>
</div>
```